# Sorting column data in Excel when one cell has multiple values seperated by a comma

Tags: excel, sorting, columnsorting

I have two columns to look at here. In each corresponding cell, their are multiple values all seperated by a comma. Here's how it looks:

| Column A (States) | Column B (Dates) |
| --- | --- |
| (Cell A2): Ohio, Georgia, Alabama | (Cell B2): 06-01-2021, 04-01-2021, 10-01-2021 |
| (Cell A3): Alaska, Utah, California | (Cell B3): 11-01-2021, 12-01-2021, 06-01-2021 |

So you can see that a single cell can have multiple sets of data that is separated by a comma. The state relates to the date, so in the cell A2 example: Ohio is 06-01-2021, Georgia is 04-01-2021, and Alabama is 10-01-2021.

The issue here is that I am needing the dates sorted from oldest to newest, and have the states adjust with that change. I have tried sorting, but since one cell contains multiple values that doesn't seem to work.

The reason the workbook is in this format is because I used a group_concat query in MySQL and now I am needing analysis here. I have tried for hours here and I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Expected output for Cell A2 and B2 would be this:

| Column A (States) | Column B (Dates) |
| --- | --- |
| (Cell A2): Georgia, Ohio, Alabama | (Cell B2): 04-01-2021, 06-01-2021, 10-01-2021 |

The example above is correct because the dates are in the oldest to newest order, and the states adjusted with that as well. I have 30k rows of data here.

Comment: Sometimes the oldest date may be the first value, second value, or third value. Your example is helpful here, but I have 30k rows of this data where the oldest value could be in any order, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @bigben51. I edited it above, what I was meaning by that statement is that the expected output example is correct because the dates are in the oldest to newest order, and the states sorted with them.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I am on Microsoft 365 which is I believe is Excel 2019.

Comment: But you want the rows to stay sorted as they currently are, correct? You just want to change the display of each cell?

Comment: This will get you column B sorted (place in column c or d), however I'm not sure how to get the states to matchup... `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(TEXT(SORT(FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,",","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"),1,1),"MM-DD-YYYY")))`

Is VBA an option?

Comment: Correct @pgSystemTester. Once the cell changes for the DATES, the cell for the STATE should change as well.

Comment: If VBA was acceptable, I could post a VBA UDF function solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Windows Office 365, you can use formulas,

- `FILTERXML` converts the strings into arrays
- `SORT` is used to sort the Dates in order
- `SORTBY` is used to sort the States in the sorted date order

*If you have Office 365 but on a Mac, you won't have the `FILTERXML` function, but there are other ways to create the necessary array from the comma separated list*

**Sorted States**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,SORTBY(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"),(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"))))
```

**Sorted Dates**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXT(SORT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s")),"m/d/yyyy"))
```

[image]

You can also do this in Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"States", type text}, {"Dates", type text}}),

/*Sort the string of Dates 
    Split the string into a List and trim each element
    Transform each list element into a "real date"
    Sort the list of dates
    Convert each date into a text string with the same format as original column
    Combine the list of dates back into a comma separated string
*/
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Sorted Dates", each Text.Combine(
        List.Transform(
            List.Sort(
                List.Transform(
                    List.Transform(
                        Text.Split([Dates],","), each Text.Trim(_)),
                    each Date.FromText(_))
                ), each Date.ToText(_,"M/d/yyyy")),
                    ", "), Text.Type),

/*Sort the string of states
    Split the string of states, string of dates, and string of sorted dates into a trimmed list
    Find the Position of each Date (from sorted List) in the Unsorted List
    Use that position as an Index into the unsorted State list to create a sorted state list
    Combine the sorted state list into a comma separated string
*/
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Sorted States", each 
        let 
            dts = List.Transform(Text.Split([Dates],","),each Text.Trim(_)),
            srtDts = List.Transform(Text.Split([Sorted Dates],","), each Text.Trim(_)),
            sts = List.Transform(Text.Split([States],","),each Text.Trim(_)),
            
            states = List.Generate(
                ()=> [state=sts{List.PositionOf(dts,srtDts{0})}, idx=0],
                each [idx] < List.Count(dts),
                each [state = sts{List.PositionOf(dts,srtDts{[idx]+1})}, idx = [idx]+1],
                each [state])
        in 
            Text.Combine(states,", "), Text.Type),

//Remove unneeded column and reorder the date/state columns        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"States", "Dates"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Sorted States", "Sorted Dates"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

**Original**
[image]

**Sorted**
[image]